# boot menu doesn't appear after upgrading to OS X Yosemite

Tags: dual-boot

I was using both OS X Mavericks and Ubuntu but after upgrading to OS X Yosemite I can't see the boot menu. I have tried both rEFIt and rEFInd but both doesn't work . Also have tried --alldrivers while again installing rEFInd .

Answer (score 1):

did you "reinstalled" refit manually?

If you didn't, try running this on the OSX Terminal

cd /efi/refit

./enable.sh

When prompted for password, use the one Yosemite asks you while trying to install new software.

After that, you should see the boot menu after you restart.
When you choose to load Ubuntu from the boot menu, you may be greeted by the "grub rescue terminal" instead of a normal boot, let me know.

By the way, you can also press the option key ("alt") just after you hit the power button, and there you'll see some options, including refit. This has the drawback that it must be done on every boot, hence the preference for the terminal solution.